# Cake php host in server with multiple domain

Tags: cakephp

I have a server with many domains/ applications on it. I need to host a cake php application on that server. When I uploaded, I get errors w.r.t urls.

for eg, www.xyz.com/aboutus. this url is working. there is a controller called Aboutus.
But when I take the url www.xyz.com/aboutus/add, it must go to the add method in Aboutus controller. It is working in my local system. But in live, it shows the error that 'add' controller is missing.

In my local, I have changed the document root in apache. But in live server I cant do this as there are multiple sites.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the `ROOT`, `APP_DIR`, and `CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH` variables in each site's webroot/index.php have been updated to go to the right paths. [[details here]](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html?highlight=advanced%20installation)  (or see below where I list my settings)  Other than that, just make sure your host has mod rewrite on and you should be good to go.

According the the CakePHP book for 2.0.x, it's easier to just change the include_path, but I haven't tried that yet:  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/deployment.html#multiple-cakephp-applications-using-the-same-core

The file-structure I use:

```
/cakephp
    /cakephp_1_3
    /cakephp_2_0_5
/public_html
    /mysite1.com
    /mysite2.com
    /mysite3.com

//webroot/index.php (of one of my sites)
define('ROOT', DS.'home'.DS.'myusername'.DS.'public_html');
define('APP_DIR', DS.'mysite1.com');
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', DS.'home'.DS.'myusername'.DS.'cakephp'.DS.'cakephp_2_0_5'.DS.'lib');
```

(I just took the 3 lines that set the variables - they're not really three lines in a row like that)

Don't forget to make sure your database settings are still correct in `app/Core/Config/database.php`