# Multiple apps using the same CakePHP core

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am currently using `CakePHP 2.1.x` and what I would like to do is use one core install of cakePHP for many apps on the same domain.

This is what my current structure looks like.

```
/var/www
    /app/
        /webroot
    /lib
        /Cake
    /plugins
    /vendors
```

What I would like to be able to accomplish is
mydomain.com/myApp1
mydomain.com/myApp2
mydomain.com/myApp3

```
/var/www
    /apps/
        /myApp1
        /myApp2
        /myApp3
    /lib
        /Cake
    /plugins
    /vendors
```

in the above scenario I'm not sure where `/webroot` would go or if there would be multiple `/webroot` folders. Also if I have to keep `/app` called `/app` or if I can call it `/apps` instead.

I'm also unsure of which `.htaccess` file(s) would have to be modified. Is this scenario possible? Is it a bad idea to do it this way?

Comment: I am sure this is a duplicate....

Comment: It might be similar, but it's not a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP Shared core for multiple apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706245/cakephp-shared-core-for-multiple-apps)

Comment: possible duplicate of this too:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880155/cake-php-host-in-server-with-multiple-domain/8881860#8881860

Comment: [CakePHP One Core, Many Apps](http://rickguyer.com/cakephp-one-core-many-apps/) if he still doesn't figure out what he needs to with the previous answers.