# In CakePhP 3.0 how do you set up multiple domains on 1 Linux server all sharing the same CakePhp core?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

This question has been answered for CakePhP 2.0 and a few people have given info about the `index.php` or the `.htaccess` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304277/multiple-apps-using-the-same-cakephp-core), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706245/cakephp-shared-core-for-multiple-apps) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880155/cake-php-host-in-server-with-multiple-domain/8881860#8881860).  But I'm asking about about the overall directory structure for doing this in CakePHP 3.0.

AFAIK it's conventional to `cd` to `/var/www/html/` and do the composer command:

`\# composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app app`

Then you'd have this directory structure:

`/var/www/html/app/`

The entire "Get the ovens ready" project then resides in that `app/` directory.  Then what sort of directory structure should you set up after that for your other domains?

Doing another composer command to create `/var/www/html/app1/` wouldn't be sharing the CakePHP Core would it?  So what directories am I supposed to set up and for each domain, and what directories get shared?

Comment: What is the benefit of sharing the same cakephp core?

Comment: Less disk space used (may be a concern in shared hosting environments), only one copy to keep up-to-date, possible performance improvement since it's more likely that the hard drive cache has the required files saved, and less general clutter.

I haven't looked into this, but it seems that maybe customizing composer.json would allow for moving things around?